# PNG images not displayed with Qt and Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, png, qt5

My application is developped using Visual Studio 2010 and the Qt5 framework.

I've created a qrc resources file using the Qt VS-addin, with some PNG images inside.
The QRC file is included in the Resources section of my VS project.

But my images are still not displayed on Windows on runtime, neither in debug or release build.
The Linux port of my application displays these images.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Edit: I'm using Qt Designer to load images, using QLabel. That said, manually specifying the PNG image using setPixmap() doesn't work neither.

Edit 2: Apparently, the problem seems to be caused by the qrc file which has an underscore in its name. Renaming the qrc in a more conventional way fixed the issue. I guess that using special characters in such files require escaping or sort of.

Comment: Read http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html especially the **Qt plugins** chapter

Comment: Among all image formats supported by Qt, PNG support is builtin and does not require any external plugin loading. Additionnally, as I'm launching my application on my pre-configured development machine, even if I needed any specific Qt plugin, it would be automatically loaded.

Comment: Code? --------------------

Comment: Huytard, please see the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, here is copy of my comment above.

Apparently, the problem seems to be caused by the qrc file which has an underscore in its name. Renaming the qrc in a more conventional way fixed the issue. I guess that using special characters in such files require escaping or sort of.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Qt` directory there is a folder named `plugins`, inside plugins folder, a folder with the name `imageformats` exists, copy `imageformats` folder to your compilation output directory.

Comment: I already fixed the problem, which is not caused by a missing pluging. As I stated above, PNG image format support in builtin with Qt. Please see above.